# Write lines to a text file during program execution - faster way

Tags: c

I'm working in C and I need to write certain output values to a text file. These values will be written to the file at different points of the script.

I'm talking about 50 lines divided in a total of 5 min of execution time.

My script is testing hardware performances (including cpu and disk caches) so it's very important that nothing slows it down or uses memory.

Is it better to use fopen() and fclose() every time that I want to write a line or just to leave the file open for the entire execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have it both ways - you have to either use memory or use disk cache. Normally, one would save the stats in memory and write them at the end of the test. However, if minimising memory use is what you want, open the file at start of the test and write the stats as you go.

Answer (score 4):

Why not store everything in memory and write it all in one go ? I mean use arrays of structures or something like that. When time comes, write it all (`fwrite` ?).

If you think this will use memory and disrupt your tests, ask yourself this: won't `I/O` disrupt your tests ? Is there any other way to store information ?

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but - "so it's very important that nothing slows it down or uses memory."

Comment: @MByD I just saw that. Still, between doing I/O and using some buffer, what seems the most disruptive ?

Comment: +1, any kind of I/O will access more memory than this anyway, so if this messes up timings then pretty much anything will.

Answer (score 0):

Are these outputs part of your disk cache test? If not, why not write directly to a serial port & let another program read that serial port & write your files? Just a thought.

The other thing you can do is to write a string that goes "echo  >> file.txt" and then pass this string to the system() function (on UNIX) or the equivalent in windows.

If that's not an option, write the output to stdout & then write a short script to pick it up & write to the file for you.

Comment: I can't run another program at the same time. Plus, I think that writing to stdout will slow down my tests...

Answer (score 0):

As Neil says you can't have it both ways. Both memory allocation and I/O operations tend to be expensive in time. Unless you are running on a real tiny machine, allocating a large buffer *before timing tests start* and then filling it for writes may be best.

```
   FILE * fid = fopen( path, "w" );
   if ( !fid ) error();
   setvbuf( fid, NULL, _IOFBF, BLKSIZ * n )
```

where "n" determines how much space you want to set up. <stdio.h> will handle all the buffering busy work for you, including releasing the buffer when the file closes.

Keep everything small enough, including buffers, so you don't trigger VM swapping or every timing test will go bad on you. Can you run with lots of RAM and without swap files?

Comment: Yes, tests will be perfomed on machines with at least 4GiB of RAM and with swap off. However the problem is that every time that I want to write a buffer, it will be copied into the cache.